# НЕ могу обрушатся к классу: System.DateOnly ПРИ создании проекта на Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.8

ребята у мены такая проблема: 1) когда создаю Консольный проект на .нет 6.0 там без проблем есть класс DateOnly, НО когда пытаюсь создать проект на WinForms (а там максимальная версия  .Net 4.8) вот в WinForms, НЕ могу найти класс DateOnly НЕ с  помощью  --> Using System;  НЕ System.DateOnly dateonly;
там есть класс DateTime, ест Timespan Но вот DateOnly нету, как его найти? :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Её там и не должно быть, она только для .NET 5, 6. [Пруф](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) (листайте в самый низ)

Comment: ооо.... а WinForms нельзя на .нет 5.6 и выше поставить?

Comment: Можно конечно, при создании проекта укажите .NET 6

Comment: так а у меня максимум 4.8 показывает на WinForms а вот когда Консоль создаю там только 6.0 ://////////

Comment: Внимательно смотрите тип проекта, в студии [их 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy0Vz.png), где с припиской `(.NET Framework)` создается проект, основанный на устаревшем .NET Framework, а не .NET. Будьте внимательней!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .NET Framework 4.8 нет того что вам нужно, и не должно быть.

Не тот тип проекта выбираете, надо вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И потом вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, помогли сильно

Comment: я вас понял :)))